# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: Screen freezing and glitching after hard reboot

Tags: 20.04, graphics

After I reset my PC (because of freeze; too much programs) with power button, if I start any app after logging in, the screen starts glitching. I was able to move my mouse and interact with windows (like writing to terminal).
I tried using CTRL+ALT+F3 before logging for the terminal so I could get Kernel and Shell info and it worked fine.

In the first 2 reboots it glitched and threw me back to login.

If I start with recovery mode (graphics drivers off) it works normally and shows windows without glitching.
I think GPU is fine because when I turned on Windows 10 the graphics worked normally.

[Video of my desktop.](https://youtu.be/cX4Ms0qBLlE)

PC info:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64

Kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic

Shell: bash 5.0.17

MEM total: 3.7 GB

CPU: Intel Pentium G3460 (2) @ 3.500

GPU: Intel HD Graphics

---

EDIT: Got syslog, fragment of it [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vQv4GN0Ls7ZG3tOILwuA0MDxmHshedpL/view?usp=sharing)

---

EDIT 2: **Fixed.** I only had to boot Ubuntu with newer kernel.

---

EDIT 3: Now I know what causes the actual bug. GNOME is broken in 5.8.0 kernels.

---

EDIT 4: turns out its most prolly xorg